# OR_BIBED_06 error in Google Pay test environtment

Tags: javascript, payment-processing, google-pay

I'm trying to set up Google Pay in test mode for a website (not for an Android app). My Processor is Fiserv - CardPointe which says to use CARDCONNCT as the gateway. When the Google Pay window pops up it displays this error.

> Something went wrong
> This merchant is having trouble accepting your payment right now. Try using a different payment method. [OR_BIBED_06] OR_BIBED_06

I'm not seeing a lot about this error on Google. But I'm thinking this is a problem with Fiserv. Here is my code

```
<script>
    function googlePayLoaded() {
        googlePayClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({ environment: 'TEST' });
        console.log("Google Pay Client loaded");
    }
</script>
<script id="googlePay" src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js" async onload="googlePayLoaded()"></script>
```

And the code that runs on the Donation page at start up and creates the button

```
const allowedPaymentMethods = ["CARD", "TOKENIZED_CARD"];
const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];
googlePayMerchantID = settingValue(settings, "GooglePayMerchantID");
googlePayMerchantName = settingValue(settings, "GooglePayMerchantName");
// also called IsReadyToPayRequest in the docs
googlePayConfig = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: allowedPaymentMethods
}
paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, googlePayConfig);
// currency code is ISO 4217 code
// country code is ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code for where the transaction is processed
paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = {
    totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
    totalPrice: "0",  // will change this later
    currencyCode: "USD",
    countryCode: "US"
}
paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
    merchantId: googlePayMerchantID,
    merchantName: googlePayMerchantName
}
const tokenizationSpec = {
    type: "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
    parameters: {
        gateway: 'CARDCONNECT',
        gatewayMerchantId: CardPointeMerchantID
    }
}
const cardPaymentMethod = {
    type: "CARD",
    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpec,
    parameters: {
        allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks,
        allowedAuthMethods: ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]
        //billingAddressParamters: {
        //    format: "FULL",
        //    phoneNumberRequired: false
        //}
    }
}
paymentDataRequest.shippingAddressRequired = false;
paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];

googlePayClient.isReadyToPay(googlePayConfig).then(function (response) {
    if (response.result) {
        vm.showGooglePayOption = true;
        const googlePayButton = googlePayClient.createButton({
            buttonColor: "default",
            buttonType: "donate",
            onClick: donateWithGooglePay
            //allowedPaymentMethods: [cardPaymentMethod]
        });
        $("#googlePayButton").html(googlePayButton);
    } else {
        console.log("Google Pay not ready");
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And then when you click the button it does this

```
function donateWithGooglePay2() {
    paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo.totalPrice = vm.data.amount.toString();
    googlePayClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest).then((paymentData) => {
        token = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
        if (vm.paymentProcessor === "CardPointe") {
            tokenized = true;
            donate2();  // this uses the token to authorize a payment 
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        // errors will be displayed in the Google Pay window
        console.log(error);
        return;
    });
}
```

Any thoughts?

PS here is my resulting paymentdatarequest object
[image: paymentDataRequest object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no call to Fiserv during the Google Pay tokenization process. Use `paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token` at the end of the process to send the token to your backend and finally over to Fiserv for the actual authorization.

To get rid of the `OR_BIBED_06` error change the following in your code:

1. in the `tokenizationSpec` object it should be `parameters` and not `paramters`
2. in the `allowedAuthMethods` array it should be `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` and not `CRYPOGRAM_3DS`
3. `totalPrice` must be a string
4. Use `cardconnect` instead of `CARDCONNECT`
5. `const allowedPaymentMethods = ["CARD", "TOKENIZED_CARD"];` can be removed. You set it correctly later in the code: `paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];`
6. `allowedPaymentMethods: allowedPaymentMethods` inside the `googlePayConfig` object can be removed.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rumwj0av/5/

Comment: Thx, I updated my code as suggested but still getting the same error

Comment: please share your new code?

Comment: I updated the code in the question

Comment: @nuander I updated the list and added a working example. of course I replaced all your variables (like `settingValue(settings, "GooglePayMerchantID");`) with a simple test string.

Comment: using cardconnect instead of CARDCONNECT was what really got this working for me.